# Change docx4j Table Cell Background Color

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I am currently trying to create a .docx Document using docx4j.
I have already created a few tables, and want to change the background- and text-color of the first table row.
[table in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qBOH.png)

I would like to create a void function which gets a Tc (table cell) and String (color) as an argument.
I actually havent found any help online.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Docx4j Helper WordAddin](https://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-helper-addin-new-installer-available-t2946.html) or [webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html) to generate Java code from a suitable example docx.